Current salary is 15% below the range on updated job posting
I accepted my current job as a junior software engineer offer in December of 2022. California's SB 1162 went into effect on January 1, 2023 so there was no stated salary range on the job description at the time I accepted the offer. Because the offer was 33% better than my previous position's salary, I didn't feel the need to try to negotiate for more. Clearly that was a mistake.
Almost 6 months ago I started getting company emails advertising bonus incentives for recommending prospective candidates to available positions. More recently one of the listings included a description of my current job. The salary range included in the position description is 15%-65% higher than my current salary.
I'm unsure how to proceed with this information, but I have a lot of questions that I am having difficulty finding answers to elsewhere online:

How often do companies work outside of the ranges?
Should I bring this up to my manager now or wait until promotion opportunity (supposedly happening soon) and attempt to renegotiate?

I genuinely enjoy working at the company and do not want to unintentionally sour the relationship with the leadership. That being said, things are getting more expensive every day and I think it's reasonable that I receive market rate compensation for my work.

See many past questions about how to ask for, and help your boss justify, a pay raise. Remember that "fairness" has nothing to do with it, that in many companies salary adjustment occurs at a specific time of the year, and that a higher hiring salary may actually mean the company is planning to wait longer before giving those people a raise so you may be comparing apples and orangutans.

So, a Year and a half without a Payrise?
If they are advertising the same position that you are currently in for a higher salary, then absolutely you can ask to be compensated appropriately.
Things you want to think about though is how you would justify your pay rise, outside of the mere fact you are being underpaid:

What projects have you worked on that have been successful?
What skills or certifications have you acquired?
What initiatives have you taken?

It is one thing to say "I am not being paid market rates", but it is quite another thing to say "I am not being paid market rates, and here is all the things I have done in the last year that justify a salary review"
You want to stack the deck as much in your favor as possible when you have the conversation about pay.

This answer is spot on. You can always ask. When you do, remember "Entitled" is not a meaningful word. The value that you is drastically more meaningful. You are already trained, up to speed on the projects, and can show a list of accomplishments. That is why you are worth more then entry level.

I am a financial analyst and I can explain how it works in the background from budgeting perspective.
In order to add an FTE (full time employee) to the company's budget that FTE needs 1) to be approved 2) the pay range needs to be approved as well. You were hired according to the budget 'requirements' - at a certain time frame (1 -st Quarter for example) and at an established rate (salary).
The other FTE  you are talking about could have been approved at a higher pay rate OR maybe the other FTE (i.e. expense) hits different cost center (i.e. department).
You will never know what exactly happened (unless you have a friend in finance to take a look) but what did happen had it logical reasons behind it. You do not see the whole picture that is why the situation makes no sense to you.
As for the emotional part - I can relate because this is very common. Please do not take it personally. I would make sure to gain as much experience as I can and if there is no promotion in the cards I would start looking for another job or a different role in the company.
The thing is - no matter what other people tell you or try to console you ,it will be eating you inside big time now. The whole situation stinks now and you won't be able to get over it. Unless there is a promotion in the future the damage is done. Focus on YOU and take advantage of the company by gaining as much experience as you can. ... Seems like the best course of action to me.


I genuinely enjoy working at the company and do not want to unintentionally sour the relationship with the leadership.

You need to consider your perspective on this carefully.
You've worked 18 months without a pay rise, when 12 months is typically the outer limit for at least a normal inflation pay rise, unless the market for your work has changed radically for the worse.
That is notwithstanding the salary increase that should be attributable to increased experience and overall career progression, unless your career is already over the hill.
Also, why should managers be angry that you're asking for the market rate of pay, which they are currently offering to new hires? If they are angry at the mere mention, then typically the best response is to seek market pay elsewhere.
The starting point in any negotiation should be that you're entitled to at least an inflation pay rise, without any special justification. An inflation pay rise means your employer is simply paying you the same as before, relative to the general level of wages and prices in the economy.
Next, if market demand for your occupation has surged since your pay was last set, then you'll want to go armed with information about the level of market wages for your occupation generally. You do not need to justify this by any exceptional performance in your current position - the market level is what another employer will pay for an average candidate hired fresh.
Finally, if you have performed exceptionally well in your current role, you will want to go armed with details about your achievements so as to justify why you should be paid at the higher end of the general market range.

Should I bring this up to my manager now or wait until promotion opportunity (supposedly happening soon) and attempt to renegotiate?

Unless the opportunity is already on the calendar and imminent in the next month or so, then I would start discussing the pay rise now.
Your employer obviously has no particular rhythm, otherwise they would not have gone 18 months already. If you are rebuffed, then be insistent that you want to talk about pay now.
If you delay, your manager might well attempt to "promote" you but then give you only the rise you could have achieved at your current level. You might even be denied a raise completely, as sometimes employers try to suggest the promotion itself should be seen as a favour.
If you don't get the right response, then seek better pay at a new employer. This will act as a double sting for your current employer - they will not only have to recruit someone on the market pay they could have satisfied you with, but will have to pay that same level to a new hire (who could turn out to be of a different calibre) and with the loss of your accumulated experience.

@spickermann, I don't think pay has fallen in that time. Certainly it hasn't at the OP's employer.
